# Is my CPU causing bottleneck for the whole system?

Tags: cpu, performance

I have this old laptop which I have been using for past 2 years. It works well except sometimes when I use programs like Photoshop and Eclipse, it takes a long time load. Also, there are some minor delays here and there as far as I can tell.

So, after researching a while, I thought upgrading it will be more economical than buying a new laptop. So, I went ahead with it. I have upgraded the RAM from 4GB to 8GB and install a Samsung Evo SSD to replace my old hitachi HDD.

After that, I can feel the faster boot time, loading etc. But the loading time for some of the programs hasn't improved much as I originally thought.

So, my question is is my CPU causing a bottleneck for the whole system?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "most likely yes".

Long answer is:

You should be able to feel quite a big difference from the way it was before having upgraded the SSD and memory.

But seeing as you are having problems with some quite demanding programs specifically (Photoshop and Eclipse) I would guess the CPU could be a bottleneck here. However, loading programs is usually not all that CPU intensive, but more likely to put a strain on IO activity (memory and HDD/SSD).

I would suggest you run through the "optimizer" application that came with the SSD.

Alternatively at least check the following settings manually:

- Re-run the Windows Experience Index clasification (this also detects your new SSD and changes settings accordingly)
- Remove indexing from the C:\ drive (or whatever drive Windows is on)
- Make sure you have set virtual memory to the appripriate size (I would suggest a 8192 MB *fixed* swapfile)

But the i3 1.8 GHz CPU that's in your laptop is really not that fast, as you can clearly see on [this chart](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i3-3217U+%40+1.80GHz) and read in [this article](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i3-3217U-Notebook-Processor.74465.0.html) compared to other Intel CPUs of roughly same generation.

Comment: I agree, the u-series processors are made for low power consumption not processing power. In the future you're probably better off going for an m-series one, for better performance.

Comment: thanks! I think you are right. If I want my laptop, "Cheap" and "Light", it won't be "Fast" I guess. But anyway, I think with this small upgrade, I can squeeze out may be half a year to a year usage before upgrading to a new laptop.

Comment: You can have Cheap, Light and/or Fast. Pick whichever two you like.

Comment: I would agree with this answer.  Its not so much the fact its a i3 and/or u-series processor its the fact its running at only 1.8ghz when other processors are running at 2x-2.5x faster.  Individually those programs should not have a problem but both are processors intensive programs.  The only thing that is ore intensive with Photoshop or a compiler is the I/O access.